# Environment Variables not getting set in bash_profile

Tags: linux, bash, environment-variables, profile

I have my bash_profile environment setting as follows:

```
if [ `hostname` = "devoraebs01" ]; then
   echo `hostname -f`
   . /appl_top/deverp/appl/APPSDEVERP_devoraebs01.env
```

When I log into this host, it echoes the hostname correctly. But I've noticed that when I try to execute some shell script, I get errors until I run the ". /appl_top/deverp/appl/APPSDEVERP_devoraebs01.env" manually.

Nothing appears to be incorrect with the syntax. Any idea why this isn't getting set correctly at my initial login?

Here's the entire contents of `. /appl_top/deverp/appl/APPSDEVERP_devoraebs01.env`:

```
customfile=/appl_top/deverp/appl/customDEVERP_devoraebs01.env 
if [ -f $customfile ]; then 
   . /appl_top/deverp/appl/customDEVERP_devoraebs01.env 
fi     
   . /db/u01/conf_top/DEVERP_devoraebs01/8.0.6/DEVERP_devoraebs01.env  
   . /appl_top/deverp/appl/DEVERP_devoraebs01.env
```

I am logging into the host via PuTTY.

Comment: if [ \`hostname\` == "devoraebs01" ]; ?

Comment: I don't think that's the fix. If it were, then my echo `hostname -f` would not run at login. But it does.

Comment: and in your *.env file you are exporting something?

Comment: Is it all run as the same user? Could it be a permission issue?

Comment: I don't think it's permissions as I'm able to run it just fine through the bash prompt.

Comment: Does the env file do an export of certain variables or a set?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and i) add the contents of `/appl_top/deverp/appl/APPSDEVERP_devoraebs01.env` (or, even better, just give us a minimal example that reproduces the problem) ii) explain how you log into the host since that changes what files are read at login.

Comment: I log in through putty. Nothing special. My bash_profile should be executed immediately after login.

Comment: Please _edit your question_ to add new information, it is hard to read and easy to miss in the comments. Logging in via putty is something special. It means you are launching a login shell and that `~/.bash_profile` should indeed be read. It isn't when you open a terminal for example, that's why I asked.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. However, what we need to see is what is actually being sourced. You showed us a file whose job is to just source another file. This is a pretty complex setup. Could you give us a minimal example? You could try adding `foo="bar"` to one of these files and checking whether `echo $foo` prints `bar`. Basically, you need to get to the simplest scenario that still reproduces your issue. Otherwise, we can't really help debug, not if we need to deal with 5 or 6 different files.

Comment: As @rahul noted above, this kind of thing is usually solved by running `export customfile` after it is defined.

Comment: So I should try adding that exact syntax, export customfile, after I run . /appl_top/deverp/appl/APPSDEVERP_devoraebs01.env?

Comment: It is not clear that the user is actually using `bash` as their login shell.

Answer (score 1):

`.bash_profile` does not get executed for non-login shells, so if you are running a command and expect it to load in env settings from `.bash_profile`, that will not happen.

Try creating a `.bashrc` file instead.

Comment: So I created a file called .bashrc in my home directory and moved my env settings script into there. Does not appear to run after login. Am I missing something?

Comment: I also added this to my .bash_profile to have it call .bashrc on login. It calles it but still not setting the env variable.

Comment: if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
       source ~/.bashrc
  fi